# Migrating from Bootstrap 3.0.2 to 3.4.1

Tags: security, twitter-bootstrap-3

I searched google but couldn't find any migration guide.

I'm working on a website that uses Bootstrap 3.0.2, and I am upgrading it to Bootstrap 3.4.1 because of the vulnerabilities found in <3.4.1. I know I may have to give my code a major revamp to migrate it.

I just want to know whether it's safe to use bootstrap 3.4.1? Or should I migrate to v4 instead?
Is there a migration guide for bootstrap v3.0.2 to 3.4.1 that I missed?

Answer (score 0):

If you do decide to go forward to v4 I would recommend going straight to v5 instead, the latest version. It is a lot more stable with not as much JS (even though v4 was very good).

v4 and v5 are not that different really, but the differences between v3 and v4 are huge. Most of the time this is coming down to the way attributes are detailed. In v3 navbar for example two of the attributes were `data-toggle` and `data-target`. From v4 onwards these became `data-bs-toggle` and `data-bs-target`.

I suspect those changes will be the biggest thing to do, otherwise it might not take as long as you think.

Comment: and from the security aspect, is bootstrap 3.4.1 a good choice?  i just want to save time not working on HTML and CSS changes, just want secured code from js vulnerabilities in bootstrap 3

Comment: Hi again @iWasCloud, with security do you mean from a user point of view or from a site hacking point of view? The thing is that Bootstrap itself isn't really responsible for either. It is only a frame work for web page layout mostly.

Comment: from XSS attacks, please see this https://snyk.io/test/npm/bootstrap/3.3.7

Comment: Oh OK, got yer... No. If I remember correctly that was still a bit of an issue in v4 but on checking I can't find anything about v5.1.3 being a problem.